# Change IBOutlet text to property of object returned from custom class

Tags: xcode, delegates, void, iboutlet

I'm using xCode 4.2.1 - I have an app that uses a web service and fetches some data using a custom class and NSURLConnection. The user taps a "refresh" button which starts a series of events that happen in some custom classes in my project, and I can get the object, along with the properties I want to return in a method in the MainViewController, I'm just not able to change the text of an IBOutlet to a property (NSString) of the returned object.

In my "MainViewController.h, I have an IBOutlet (and it's wired to a button in the MainViewController.xib):

```
IBOutlet UILabel *textLabel;
```

and:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *textLabel;
```

And I've synthesized the label in MainViewController.m

```
@synthesize textLabel;
```

The process looks like this:  Refresh Button Tapped --> Fires a mthod in MainViewController --> Fires another method in a custom class (retrieves data from web, creates object) --> Sends Object to MainViewController via: (in my custom class implementation)

```
// parsing, etc.. and define a string for priceString property of mp object    
MainViewController *mvc = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    [mvc log:mp];
```

And in my MainViewController.m I can access a property of that object and print it in NSLog just fine from this method.

```
- (void) log:(Price *)mp {

    self.textLabel.text = mp.priceString;
    NSLog(@"%@", mp.priceString);
}
```

At this point, I can see the data in the log, but the textLabel text won't change.

I've been trying to read examples for a week, and I've heard everything from delegation, to NSNotication answers, but nothing seems to work.

All I need to do is populate an IBOutlet from a -(void) method. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I'm down for implementing delegation, but I'm very new to it, and seeking an example.

EDIT - more details.

After further research, I think I should note that my NSURLConnection that is returning my objects is in a separate class, and I've been reading a lot of threads where people are starting the connection in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Are you sure the IBOutlet is wired in Interface Builder? To a UILabel or to a UIButton?

Comment: The outlet called textLabel is wired to a UILabel. The IBAction that starts the entire process is wired to a button in a navigation bar. The problem is after it goes out and gets all the data I need. How do I update the UI (NIB) Label <em>outside</em> of the viewDidLoad method? In other words the data getting returned comes back outside of the main thread.

Comment: Can I call this method from inside the viewDidLoad, to delay the main thread until the values get returned? - (void)performSelectorOnMainThread:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are calling `[mvc log:mp];` just after initializing the view controller. At that stage, the view is still not loaded from the xib file.

you can change `log` to see that:

```
- (void) log:(Price *)mp {
    if (self.textLabel) {
        self.textLabel.text = mp.priceString;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"textLabel is nil.");
    }
}
```

You can call `[mvc log:mp];` in the view controller `viewDidLoad` method, or after viewDidLoad has been executed.

To understand this better, add `NSLog(@"viewDidLoad.");` in `viewDidLoad` method, and add `NSLog(@"viewController initialized.");` just after the code where you initialized the view controller.

You will see the following

```
viewController initialized.
textLabel is nil. // if you call log as usual after initializing the view controller.
viewDidLoad.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but the init code you're referring to is in my custom class, not the MainViewController, which I believe is part of my problem. I'm not using a delegate, so I was simply trying to get access to the MainViewControllers UILabels in order to populate them.